# Angular JS - send data to .NET Controller API

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, api

I have this angular js code here:

`$http.post('/reports/', JSON.stringify($scope.user));`

and its hitting my Reports Controller Post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public dynamic Post(Array data){
  //do something
}
```

but when I check the data in my Post method when it hits in my breakpoint it appears as null :( how do I pass the data from $scope.user to my Controller. I did a console.log of $scope.user and the data is there, it is an object but trying to pass it in as JSON.

I found this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Customer cust)
        {
            var newCust = _Repository.InsertCustomer(cust);
            if (newCust != null)
            {
                var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
                msg.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + newCust.ID.ToString());
                return msg;
            }
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
        }
```

would I have to put [FromBody] Reports report instead of Array data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this simple as possible, you are missing the parameter name:

```
$http.post('/reports/', {data: $scope.user});
```

Make sure that `$scope.user` is an Array, else change the type.

Comment: Array is just something I put in there for now, I am looking to pass in JSON data to my .NET API Controller

Comment: The controller will bind the object to It correspondent at the parameter. Just pass the write thing.